# how to get the url of selected image in a listbox populated by flickr feed in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, flickr

i am using the public feed from flickr to display the thumbnails of images in a listbox. I need to get the url of the selected image so that i can load the full image below the listbox. How to do so?[the feed url is here](http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tag=nokia)

```
XElement XmlTweet = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

       XNamespace ns = "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"; // flilckr
       listBox1.ItemsSource = from tweet in XmlTweet.Descendants("item")
                               select new FlickrData
                               {

                                   ImageSource = tweet.Element(ns + "thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value,
                                   Message = tweet.Element("description").Value,
                                   UserName = tweet.Element("title").Value,
                                   PubDate = DateTime.Parse(tweet.Element("pubDate").Value)

                               };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register SelectionChanged Event of listbox, in that

```
  void ListboxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      Listbox list = sender as Listbox;
      FlickrData data = list.SelectedItem as FlickrData;

      string url = data.ImageSource ;
   }
```